# Cocoa NSView: overlapping view's doesn't block controls underneath

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, nsview

I have 2 views 1 view has NSTextFields (viewA) the other one (viewB) just overlaps viewA

but i can still on the textfields even though viewB completly overlaps the textfields.

is there an easy way to block this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mouse events go to whoever will accept them, so put

`- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent { }`

in View B.